# How to print scripts command in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

We have tons of repo, every repo is setup differently, I have to open package.json many times to recheck the scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev"
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev webpack --env.env dev",
}
```

I wonder if there's a command to print the list of command in my terminal.

Comment: @derpirscher If OP use yarns or gulp will that still work too?

Comment: @JGFMK if the question is tagged with "npm" it should be safe to assume OP uses "npm" ... If that's not the case (or the commands are to be used from somewhere else) OP should update the question accordingly to express what she really needs ...

Comment: @derpirscher I reedit my question

Comment: Well. The answer is the same `npm run` without addtional arguments ...

Comment: @derpirscher you're a genius

Answer (score 1):

you can import it directly.

```
const jennylol = require("./package.json")
```

jennylol.derpirscher assume the json key is "derpirscher" , and tara you get that without look the docs like @derpirscher mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For NPM: `npm run`

For Yarn Classic (and maybe Yarn 2 as well, but I haven't checked): `yarn run`